# Displaying different content depending on variable

Tags: plugins, query, content

I'm making a web app that shows information about a type of truck - if the user wants to view their content in metric or imperial they click the respective box in the header - I want to change the content of the page to reflect the right system - ideally by not using two different subdomains or pages - thanking you

Comment: Would you just change a table of statistics, or is it paragraphs of text and images too that change?

Comment: It would be different images and text - what I ended up doing was setting the classname of whatever element to something fixed example "UserRoleOneOnly" and then using javascript Header And Footer Script plugin to have javascript run a check at the end if there are any elements with that classname and to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't want to use two pages, then you have two options - load content via AJAX, or use javascript to hide some of the content (for example imperial units related content).

Second option is much more easier in my opinion, but it may slow down your page, so it's not recommended when there is a lot of content.